# Angular material md-sidenav set md-is-open value based on screen size

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

i am trying to set md-is-open based on screen size. Something like $mdMedia('gt-sm'). For md-is-locked-open can be set with $mdMedia('gt-sm'), but don't know why md-is-open can't set with that. Currently my code look like:
`<md-sidenav md-is-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')"></md-sidenav>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav), `md-is-open`attribute can be

> A model bound to whether the sidenav is opened.

Hence, you can define a model in your controller and assign it to `md-is-open` attribute, such as

```
// Controller
$scope.shouldLeftBeOpen = $mdMedia('gt-sm');
```

And you can use it like

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-open="shouldLeftBeOpen"></md-sidenav>
```

Here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/turgutsaricam/pen/VaWZNr). When you load the page from a device whose width is less than 960px, sidenav won't be opened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is works. Never though before to put the $mdMedia('gt-sm') at model.